# How to create a custom rule that uses the remote method?

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

Using the [jQuery Validation Plugin](http://jqueryvalidation.org/), is there a way to create a custom rule using `$.validator.addMethod` that utilizes the `remote` functionality?

I have tried the following code:

```
$.validator.addMethod("custom-remote", function (value, element, param) {
    if (this.optional(element)) {
        return true;
    }

    return $.validator.methods.remote.call(this, value, element, {
        url: "/checkvalue",
        type: "POST",
        data: {
            valueToCheck: value
        }
    });
}, jQuery.format("{0}"));
```

Which only works if you change focus on the input before the remote request finishes.

I do not want to use `$.ajax()` with `async: false` as that could possibly create a poor user experience in this case.

Comment: If you can't just use `remote` rule and need a custom method, then you don't need `remote` at all.   Simply use `.ajax()` inside your custom method.

Comment: Also, WHY are you doing this in the first place?  I see nothing in your custom method that the default `remote` method doesn't already do by itself.  Your code is nothing more than a method inside of itself.  Just use the `remote` rule as it was designed.

Comment: @Sparky I was under the impression that the `addMethod` had to return right away which meant that you needed to use `async: false` with the ajax request which I do not want to do as it could lead to a bad user experience. As for why, this is a simple example to show what I want to do. Also, I have a number of other custom validation `addMethod` calls that do not use remote and I wanted to stay consistent.

Comment: Then look more closely at my first comment.  You are basically wanting to create a modified version of the `remote` rule.  Start by looking at the default `remote` rule and build it from that... (hint:  use `.ajax()`).  Although, you don't need to write a whole new method to simply modify `remote`'s `ajax()` options.